# Two format parameters TinyMCE WordPress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

Is it possible to adding two format parameters (like 'h3' & 'span') for one customized style in TinyMCE for WordPress. I want to create a custom style header that looks like this:

```
 <h3 class="headerclass"><span>Headertitle</span></h3>
```

I'm using an array in a [function](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/adding-custom-styles-in-wordpress-tinymce-editor/) in my function.php that look like this:

```
array(
        'title' => '--Hedaer--',
        'block' => 'h3',
        'classes' => 'headerclass',
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. There might be a better way of doing the inline span but I would add it as an additional style to select from the styles dropdown.

```
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'editor_styles' );

function editor_styles( $buttons ) {
    array_unshift( $buttons, 'styleselect' );
    return $buttons;
}

add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'editorstyles_init' );

function editorstyles_init( $settings ) {

    $style_formats = array(

        array(
            'title' => 'Header',
            'block' => 'h3',
            'classes' => 'headerclass'
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Header inline',
            'inline' => 'span'
        ),
    );

    $settings['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );

    return $settings;

}
```

Comment: But this means I first have to select "Header" and then "Header inline" go get my desired results? `<h3 class="headerclass"><span>Headertitle</span></h3>`

Comment: Someone else might be able to answer this better. I'd be interested to know if it can be done as well so I'll keep an eye out.

Comment: Just had a thought - if you're using jQuery maybe a workaround could be something like $('body .headerclass').each(function() { $(this).wrapinner('<span />'); }); http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/

Comment: I had a thought of this too but it dosn't work. Nothing happens and I get no errors.

Comment: No errors at all in the console? Try changing every instance of '$' to 'jQuery'. There is no reason why this shouldn't work as long as the jQuery library is loaded. If it isn't, it should return an error to the console.

Comment: Problem solved. I'm loading some content vith ajax and had to write like this $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $('h3.fullwidthheader').each(function() {
     $(this).wrapInner('<span />'); 
 });  
})